# Scale element inside a div, and make over-flow scrollable - HTML

Tags: html, css

I have some document scan image inside in a child div.
In the parent div I defined `overflow: scroll`.
I want to create zoom-in functionality when the user clicks the scan image.

On the click event, this class is applied to the child element:

```
.zoomIn {
    -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

The issue is that the document inside the child div scales and gets cropped along the edges.

How can I maintain the size of the document on scale and just make it scrollable?

[EDIT]

I sorry that i can't add the code, it because all those elements are rendered dynamically into the DOM from angular component.
I tried all your suggestions and it still the same.
I notice that when I add width on click it working like it should be, but it scales the image from top left corner is it possible to scale it from the center when increasing the width?

Comment: can you show us your html

Comment: As for scaling it from the center - you'll need to adjust the scroll position using `js`. css will not accomplish that

Answer (score 0):

I underestood that u have 2 divs, a child and a parent one, and u want to click on the child and zoom in, your problem is that  when you zoom in, the child size makes bigger and changes the parent size, and you want to make the child bigger without changing parent size

Option 1:
Change to `Overflow:auto;` to the parent div via css

Option 2:
Set a `max-width:1100px;` to parent div, u can choose the px

Answer (score 0):

It might be because the image and the `div` scales when the `.zoomIn` class is added.

[Original Problem - JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Examath/eng952ud/)

It could be solved by using the `img` inbuilt scrolling method:

```css
.parent {
  overflow: scroll;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.zoomIn {
    -moz-transform: scale(1.5);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
    transform: scale(1.5);    
}
```

```html
<img onclick="this.classList.add('zoomIn')" class="parent" src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-OHKK5CysDvM/TeYP-E9XaLI/AAAAAAAAAHw/wCimgXNWVCc/s1600/P3226278.jpg" />
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Examath/x4b8cy7z/)